# Python: Extend a 1D array in heterogeneous steps provided by the values in another 1D array

Tags: python-3.x

I have two equally long 1D arrays: "Number_of_Data" and "Value". With these two arrays, I would like to create a third array ("Final_Array") where each of the element values in "Value" appears as many times as specified by the corresponding element value in "Number_of_Data".

Let me give you an example:

```
import numpy as np
# Create the Arrays
Number_of_Data = np.asarray([2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 3])
Value = np.arange(0, 7, 1)

# Then, somehow, I want Final_Array to be:
Final_Array 
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6])
```

Is there a python function to accomplish this? (In reality, my arrays are of course much longer than the length of "Value" and the maximum number of data is much higher than the highest value in "Number_of_Data")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any numpy integrated function. The easiest approach is to create a simple function that takes the two arrays and gives you back the desired vector exploiting two for loops.

```
import numpy as np


def final(numbers, values):
    n_values = len(values)
    vector = np.zeros(np.sum(numbers))
    counter = 0
    for k in range(n_values):
        for j in range(numbers[k]):
            vector[counter] = values[k]
            counter += 1
    return vector


Number_of_Data = np.asarray([2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 6, 3])
Value = np.arange(0, 7, 1)

Final_Array = final(Number_of_Data, Value)
print(Final_Array)
```

This gives back

```
[ 0.  0.  1.  1.  1.  1.  2.  3.  3.  4.  4.  4.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  5.  6.  6.  6.]
```